# Naming a relation in Doctrine 2 ORM?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, doctrine-orm, yaml

How can i set the name of the foreign key (**edit**: not the name of the attribute itself) for the many-to-one relation "region" using YAML?

```
SWA\TestBundle\Entity\Province:
  type: entity
  table: province
  uniqueConstraints:
    UNIQUE_PROVINCE_CODE:
      columns: code
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator: { strategy: AUTO }
  fields:
    code:
      type: integer
    name:
      type: string
      length: 255
    short_name:
      type: string
      length: 2
  manyToOne:
    region:
      targetEntity: Region
      inversedBy: provinces
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look at the [getCreateConstraintSQL method in the AbstractPlatform class](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/9ec9bb9bfc7641ba0dc36e32650c0e2fefe79a06/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/AbstractPlatform.php#L1075) to see how the name of the foreign key is chosen ([line 1088](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/blob/9ec9bb9bfc7641ba0dc36e32650c0e2fefe79a06/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Platforms/AbstractPlatform.php#L1088)).

It is taken directly from the constraint name. Influencing constraint name will influence the foreign key name.

As a workaround you could drop the constraint and re-create it with a new name in [a doctrine migration](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/migrations.html).

Comment: So there is no "standard" way of changing it - apart from migration procedure? The name is completely random i guess, like FK_28392f89329.

Comment: Well, you could overload the platform class but I don't think it's worth it just for sake of naming the constraint.

Comment: How does one "influence constraint name" for foreign keys?

Answer (score 2):

Due to @JakubZalas answer, I had taken a look to the code in Github, and have seen that changing the framework code for doing what you want is really easy.

If you check the folder where AbstractPlatform class is, you'll see that there is a ForeignKeyConstraint class. In it you'll see it inherits from AbstractAsset.

Now AbstractAsset class has a _generateIdentifierName method. If you check this method **in github** you'll see that it has a commented part that does just what you want. You just uncomment this part, comment the actual active part, change the $prefix parameter to $postfix and you're done. The constraint name will be generated using the table and column names with a corresponding postfix.

The AbstractAsset.php file is the the this folder: Symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Schema

I tried in my project ant it worked fine.

One final information: at least for my project the commented part I mention above is only in github, not in the file at my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible today (Doctrine ORM 2.17) by doing this:

Create a service that listens on `postGenerateSchema`, by tagging it as follows in `services.yaml`:

```
App\Service\Listeners\SchemaListener:
    tags:
        - {name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postGenerateSchema}
```

Here, you will search for that FK, remove the doctrine-generated one and set a new one the way you want it.

In my case, I had this foreign key which cannot be changed and must remain as it is:

```
CREATE TABLE `offer_clicks` (
    [...]
    CONSTRAINT `ck_landingpage_id` FOREIGN KEY (`lp_id`) REFERENCES `landingpages` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
}
```

So this is what I did:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Event\GenerateSchemaEventArgs;

class IgnoreSchemaListener
{
    public function postGenerateSchema(GenerateSchemaEventArgs $args): void
    {
        $schema = $args->getSchema();

        foreach ($schema->getTables() as $table) {
            if ($table->getName() == 'offer_clicks') {
                foreach ($table->getForeignKeys() as $fk) {
                    if ($fk->getName() == 'FK_F98F6EA068DFD1EF') {
                        $table->removeForeignKey($fk->getName());
                        $table->addForeignKeyConstraint('landingpages', ['lp_id'], ['id'], ['onDelete' => 'CASCADE', 'onUpdate' => 'CASCADE'], 'ck_landingpage_id');
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After that, `bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` will finally say

> [OK] Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata.