# Naming indexes and foreign keys in doctrine?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have the following relation on one of my entities:

```
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="contract")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="contract_client",
*   joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_client", referencedColumnName="id_client")},
*   inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_contract", referencedColumnName="id_contract")}
```

the app/console doctrine:schema:update is generating names like FK_29A5BB4736B289B6 and IDX_29A5BB4736B289B6 for the foreign keys and indexes.

Is there a way to specify the name of these indexes/constraints ? I would like something like fk_contract_client_client

Comment: Unfortunatly you can't do that. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623958/naming-a-relation-in-doctrine-2-orm) answer.

Comment: @pazulx actually, you can. Check my answer in the link you pointed me to.

Answer (score 1):

```
#[ORM\UniqueConstraint(
    name: 'characters_idx',
    columns: ['characters']
)]
#[ORM\Entity]
```

this is how you can name indexes and constraints with attributes in entity files